# iPhone app to communicate with circuit board in non-apple-device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, wifi

We want our iPhone app to be able to communicate with a circuit board inside an air cleaner.

The circuit board inside the air cleaner should receive signals from the iPhone app, and based on those, do certain commands in the air cleaner.

So you should basically be able to use the iPhone app to control the air cleaner via bluetooth (least likely because of the Made for iPod program) or WiFi (more likely).

Which is the framework I should use?

We will order a circuit board from a company next week, and we need to know which framewoork we should build the iPhone app control with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the [NSNetService](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NetServiceBrowser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes will get you started publishing services on the networks (wifi and bluetooth) so that your circuit can connect to your iOS app. It sounds like your are going to need a pretty low level connection/messaging lib for the other side (what can you expect to run on your circuit board? C++, pure C?). Either create your own or you can look into the [C++ network library](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/) or the [C++ boost::asio library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html) and use/build on their messaging frameworks. All depends on the capabilities of your "circuit board".